# R ggplot graph won't refresh

Tags: r, shiny

I have s .csv file which looks like this:

```
 "name","task","progress","category","status"
 "Mike","call","60","HR","100% completed"
 "Josh","meeting","60","Management","100% completed"
 "Anna","interview","30","Marketing","on hold"
```

I have a submit button which adds a row in the .csv file every time is pushed, but the graph won't update only if I refresh the page.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    saveData <- function(data) {
data <- as.data.frame(t(data))

if (exists("responses")) {
  responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
} else {
  responses <<- data}

write.csv(responses, file = "read.csv", row.names = FALSE)}

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
saveData(formData()) })



output$plot<-renderPlot({
data<-read.csv("C:/Users/Desktop/project/read.csv")
ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=as.numeric(progress), group=task, fill= task, color= task)) +
geom_bar( stat="identity", position = "dodge")+theme_minimal()+
geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%1.2f%%",progress)), color="black", position=position_dodge(width=1), vjust=2)+
ylim(c(0, 100))

  })
}
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Why should it refresh? You plot gets rendered once you load the page. It reads the data once and created the plot.

Comment: You need to use [reactives](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactive.html). Also the [Shiny tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) is a great place to start learning about `Shiny`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a reactive element inside your `renderPlot()` function.

```
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
        rv <- reactiveValues(update = 0)
        saveData <- function(data) {
            data <- as.data.frame(t(data))

            if (exists("responses")) {
                responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
            } else {
                responses <<- data
            }

            write.csv(responses, file = "read.csv", row.names = FALSE)
        }

        observeEvent(input$submit, {
            saveData(formData())
            rv$update <- rv$update + 1 
        })

        output$plot<-renderPlot({
            rv$update
            data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Desktop/project/read.csv")
            ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=as.numeric(progress), group=task, fill= task, color= task)) +
            geom_bar( stat="identity", position = "dodge")+theme_minimal()+
            geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%1.2f%%",progress)), color="black", position=position_dodge(width=1), vjust=2)+
ylim(c(0, 100))

  })
}
```

This will cause `renderPlot()` to fire each time the `rv$update` element updates. You could also induce this behavior by including `input$submit` in your `renderPlot()` but because you're writing to and reading from a file it's best to force a sequential firing of the functions.